# How to call specific line in HTTP Get from XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, http, httpwebrequest

Right now I get a full dump of this XML...

http://smart-ip.net/geoip-xml/68.5.63.33

What I want my program to do is just call the city and region from that XML.

I'm new to web services so I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do this, help is much appreciated

Here is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;
XmlTextReader myXMLReader = null;

try
{
    XPathNavigator nav;
    XPathDocument docNav;

    String weatherURL = "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-xml/" + txtIP.Text;

    myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(weatherURL);
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    myXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

    docNav = new XPathDocument(myXMLReader);

    nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
    nav.MoveToRoot();
    nav.MoveToFirstChild();

    do
    {
        if (nav.NodeType == XPathNodeType.Element)
        {
            nav.MoveToFirstChild();
            do
            {
                txtIPresults.Text = txtIPresults.Text + nav.Name + " - " + nav.Value + Environment.NewLine;  //Display
            } while (nav.MoveToNext());
        }
    } while (nav.MoveToNext());
}
catch (Exception myException)
{
    throw new Exception("Error Occurred:", myException);
}
finally
{
    myHttpWebRequest = null;
    myHttpWebResponse = null;
    myXMLReader = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to get the values from the `countryName` and `city` elements from the XML response.

This can be done in the following way using the `XDocument` class from the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace:

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;

try
{
    String weatherURL = "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-xml/" + txtIP.Text;

    myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(weatherURL);
    myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
    myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    //---- <Added code> -------

    var doc = XDocument.Load(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

    var geoip = doc.Element("geoip");
    var country = geoip.Element("countryName").Value;
    var city = geoip.Element("city").Value;

    Console.WriteLine(country + " - " + city);

    //---- </Added code> -------
}
catch (Exception myException)
{
    throw new Exception("Error Occurred:", myException);
}
finally
{
    myHttpWebRequest = null;
    myHttpWebResponse = null;
}
```

It's also possible to use the `XDocument.Load()` method to load the XML response using the url string directly:

```
String weatherURL = "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-xml/" + txtIP.Text;
var doc = XDocument.Load(weatherURL);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Which parts of my code should I remove/keep when using yours

Comment: I just edited the answer, adding all the code you posted with the insertions marked between comments.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error under this line.... var doc = XDocument.Load(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

Comment: It's saying this... Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.Xml.XmlReader'

and also this.. Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(System.Xml.XmlReader)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Notice that the argument passed to `XDocument.Load()` is **not** the `myXMLReader` variable in your code but `myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`.

Comment: kk nvm I fixed it up, but now when I run it and hit the button it goes straight to the exception and says error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
     try
     {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Headers.Add();//ADD ALL YOUR HEADERS IF YOU NEED
        var xml = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://smart-ip.net/geoip-xml/{0}", txtIP.Text));

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);

        var name = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//countryName").Value;
        txtIPresults.Text = name
     }
     catch (Exception myException)
     {
        throw new Exception("Error Occurred:", myException);
     }
```

I don´t know for sure if it have more performance than HTTP REQUEST/RESPONSE but the code is very small and easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how would I make this show up in my txt box called txtResults.Text after I hit the submit button

Comment: just edited my answer, just put this within your button submit click, dont forget to add all references needed.

Comment: I'm getting an error under this line... txtIPresults.Text = name;

The error is: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XmlNode' to 'string'

Comment: Forgot to add a .Value on selectsinglenode, now it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm the error went away but now when I click the submit button nothing pops up.

Comment: you should debug to see if the variable name is getting the value you want.